# ASP.NET MVC 3 Linq uppercase or lowercase database search

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need immediate help. ): and i know little english.

**ASP.NET MVC 3 Linq uppercase or lowercase contains search**

Example:

```
string metin="baris";

var IcerikAra = (from icerik in Context.dbDokumanEditor
join kategori in Context.dbDokumanKategori on 
icerik.KategoriID equals kategori.KategoriID
where icerik.Icerik.toLower().Contains(metin)
select new { 
KategoriID=kategori.
KategoriAd=kategori.KategoriAd
}).ToList();
```

**Exception**:
**StackTrace:**

```
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommandentityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Plus.Areas.DokumanEditor.Controllers.DokumanController.DokumanIcerikAramaBaslat(String metin)
```

**Error Message:** An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

thanks..

Comment: `See the inner exception for details.` Did you do that? If, yes what did you saw? If not, go ahead.

Comment: your select block is wrong. it must be like this `select new { 
KategoriID=kategori.KategoriID,
KategoriAd=kategori.KategoriAd
}`. select kısmında sorun var, ayrıca iç hatada ne yazıyor onu da yazarsan sornunun hakkında daha doğru cevaplar alabilirsin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved as follows:

```
database datatype text -> old
database datatype nvarchar(MAX) -> new

var IcerikAra = (from icerik in Context.dbDokumanEditor
                 join kategori in Context.dbDokumanKategori on icerik.KategoriID equals kategori.KategoriID
where icerik.Icerik.ToLower().Contains(metin)
select new { 
     KategoriID=kategori.KategoriID,
     KategoriAd=kategori.KategoriAd
}).ToList();
```

Comment: The problem isn't clear, so the answer isn't clear either. Also, note that this `ToLower` conversion isn't necessary at all, because the database collation determines all string comparisons.

Comment: I changed the data type from database to nvarchar (max). If the metin variable is lowercase, it can be searched in Icerik by making a lowercase.

Comment: If the database collation is case-insensitive, which it probably is, then you do *not* need this ToLower.

Answer (score 3):

Use String.Equals in your where clause

```
where icerik.Icerik.Equals(metin,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```